# VBA Access Write to PS1 file

Tags: vba, powershell, ms-access-2016

I am trying to use Access 2016 as a front end for a database that when a user clicks a button it generates a Powershell script and runs it.

I am currently using this:

```
    Dim Script As String
Script = ("test" & vbCrLf & "2nd line?")
Set f = fileSysObject.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\%Username%\Documents\Access.ps1", True, True)
f.Write Script
f.Close
```

Then to run the script I am using:

```
    Dim run
run = Shell("powershell ""C:\Users\%Username%\Documents\Powershell\Access.ps1""", 1)
```

I realise that this is probably a really bad way of doing this! So any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

EDIT: 
Sorry there is no question!

The problem is that it highlights an error at 'f.write Script'

Compile Error: Method or data member not found.

Comment: _I realise that this is probably a really bad way of doing this!_ -- What makes you think so? Does it cause an error? Does it cause some other undesired behavior? StackOverflow isn't really suited to these kinds of open-ended questions; on-topic questions are those with a specific problem.

Comment: Help with what? There's no question in this post.

Answer (score 0):

The format `%VAR%` doesn't work in VBA, you need to `Environ("VAR")`

That said username doesn't return a value with that method, but you can use `VBA.Environ("Username")` in this case:

```
Dim strScript, strUserName, strFile As String
Dim objFSO, objFile as Object

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

strScript = ("test" & vbCrLf & "2nd line?")
strUserName = VBA.Environ("Username")
strFile = "C:\Users\" & strUserName & "\Documents\Access.ps1"

Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(strFile)
objFile.WriteLine strScript
objFile.Close

Set objFSO = Nothing
Set objFile = Nothing
```

Comment: Script, UsrName are currently defined as Variant. Maybe define them as strings. Also, where are f and filesysObject defined?

Comment: I assumed the OP had only included the relevant parts of his script, which may not be the case so I've fleshed my answer out to full code.